# How to increment an item in a shopping cart

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I'm trying to build a shopping cart and I'm using code found on Github as a starting point.

Currently, when 'Add to Cart' is clicked, it appends the same item to the cart list even though it already exists. Is there a way to increment the quantity of the item if it has already been added?

There are two components (Product Catalog & Cart) where there is some sort of add to cart functionality. I think the issue is in the cart controller but I'm unsure.

This is the product catalog controller:

```
    onClickAddToCart : function(component,event,helper){
    var selectedItem = event.currentTarget;
    var recId = selectedItem.dataset.id;
    var productName = selectedItem.dataset.name;
    var productPrice = selectedItem.dataset.price;
    var pricebookentryid = selectedItem.dataset.pricebookentryid;
    var pricebookid = selectedItem.dataset.pricebookid;
    var product = {
        productId : recId,
        quantity: 1,
        price : productPrice,
        productName : productName,
        pricebookentryid : pricebookentryid,
        pricebookid : pricebookid
    };
    $A.get("e.c:AddToCartEvent").
    setParams({
        product: JSON.stringify(product)
    }).fire();
},
```

This is the cart controller:

```
    addedToCart : function(component, event, helper) {
    var cartItems = component.get('v.cartItems');
    var productAdded = event.getParam("product");
    productAdded = JSON.parse(productAdded);
    cartItems.push(productAdded); 
    component.set('v.cartItems',cartItems);
```

Does anyone have any pointers? Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By Using **forEach**, loop the cart items and check whether the same Item is there or not. If there then **increment** the quantity else add as new Item.

```
addedToCart: function (component, event, helper) {
     var cartItems = component.get('v.cartItems');
     var productAdded = event.getParam("product");
     productAdded = JSON.parse(productAdded);
     
     var itemAlreadyAdded=false;
     
    cartItems.forEach((Item) => {
        
        if(Item.productId == productAdded.productId){
            Item.quantity = parseInt(Item.quantity)+parseInt(productAdded.quantity);//incrementing
            itemAlreadyAdded=true;
        }
    });
    
    if(itemAlreadyAdded==false){
        
        cartItems.push(productAdded);
    }
    component.set('v.cartItems', cartItems);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked - and it makes a lot of sense!

Comment: We need to update below line for increment
_Item.quantity = parseInt(Item.quantity)+parseInt(productAdded.quantity);_

We have to use **parseInt** for addition, otherwise, it will concatenate as a string.


Upvote it, If it's helpful